# Radius of convergence of a power series defined in terms of co-efficients around another point

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I'm trying to answer the following question, having a hard time figuring out where to begin. Any help appreciated:

Let f be analytic everywhere it is defined, and for $|z| < 2$ the following holds:

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^n}z^n $$

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of co-efficients for the taylor series of f around $z = \pi$, that is $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-\pi)^n$. find the radius of convergence for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ (no need to calculate the $a_n$'s).

---

I can calculate the various derivatives of f at zero based on the formula given for the co-efficients around zero above, but having a hard time figuring out how to go from there. Its supposed to be related to the textbook material to do with the uniqueness principle for complex analytic functions

Comment: Hint: there is a nice formula for $f(z)$  for $|z| < 2$.

Comment: Actually the question is not quite correct as stated.  You need to assume that $f$ is defined on a **connected** domain containing both $\{z: |z| < 2\}$ and a neighbourhood of $\pi$.  As currently stated, you might have $f$ defined only on $\{z: |z| < 2\}$ and a neighbourhood of $\pi$ disjoint from that, and it could be any analytic function at all in that neighbourhood of $\pi$, in which case the radius of convergence could be anything in $(0, +\infty]$.

Comment: I agree the definition of where f is defined is a little murky which made me hesitate as well.. assuming it is defined on a connected domain as you suggest, how do we go about it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I figured out a way to show that at least in that radius of convergence around zero the function can be given as f(z) = 1 / (1 - z/2)^2 .. not sure where to go from there though assuming that f is indeed defined on a connected domain.. I know it has to do with the identity theorem

Comment: The identity theorem tells you $f(z) = 1/(1-z/2)^2$ on the whole domain.  Then we may as well take the domain to be $\mathbb C \backslash \{2\}$. Now $f(z)$ is analytic in a disk of radius $\pi - 2$ around $\pi$, so ...

Comment: so the radius of convergence for the taylor series of f around $\pi$ is $\pi-2$, therefore we can say the radius of convergence for that same series but centered at zero is $\pi-2$ as well? do I need a formal argument for the last step where we can shift the center and use same co-efficients / get same radius of convergence?

Comment: Complex power series define complex analytic functions, and by Hadamard, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of the function at $p$ is the distance from $p$ to the nearest singularity of the function. Since this function is $\frac 4{(z-2)^2}$, its only singularity is at $z = 2$. So the Taylor series at $z = \pi$ will have $|\pi - 2|$ as its radius of convergence. Note that the coefficients at $z = \pi$ are *not the same* as the coefficients at $z= 0$

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you - the question asks me specifically about the radius of convergence of the series at zero *but using the same co-efficients as defined for the series around pi*. Its a bit confusing (see my original statement of the question) but I take it that since radius of convergence has a formula based on the co-efficients only (e.g. based on a limit involving the $a_n$ )it is the same if we use the same co-efficients but move the "center"?

Comment: This is a question you can answer yourself if you just recall what the exact definition of the radius of convergence of a power series is. Perhaps it would be more obvious if you used a different variable than $z$ in the second power series centered at $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - right, if I mark say ζ = z - π , then $f(ζ) = \sum a_n ζ^n$ should have the same radius of convergence as $f(z) = \sum a_n (z-\pi)^n$ no?

Comment: Why are you asking me? Is that what the definition of radius of convergence says?

Comment: yes because the radius of convergence depends on the co-efficients only!